# Why am I leaking memory here (depth first search) c++?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, memory-leaks, depth-first-search

```
int Solver::negamax(Position* pos,int alpha,int beta, int color, int depth ) {
  if(depth==0 || is_final(pos)){
    return evaluate(pos);
  }
  else{
    vector < Position* > moves = generate_moves(pos->get_board());
    vector < Position* >::iterator move;
    int min = 99999;
    for(move = moves.begin(); move < moves.end(); move++){
      int val = negamax(*move,alpha, beta, -color, depth - 1 );
      if(val <= min){
        min = val;
        delete best;
        best = NULL;
        best = (*move)->get_board();

      }
      else{
        delete *move; //So this isnt cleaning up?
        *move = NULL;
      }
     }
     min = -min;
     return min;
     }

 }

vector < Position* > TakeAwaySolver::generate_moves(Board *brd){
  TakeAwayBoard *board = static_cast<TakeAwayBoard*>(brd);
  vector < Position* > moves;
  if(board->get_data() >= 3){
     TakeAwayBoard *b = new TakeAwayBoard(board->get_data() - 3);
     Position* p = new Position(b);
     moves.push_back(p);
  }
  if(board->get_data() >= 2){
     TakeAwayBoard *b = new TakeAwayBoard(board->get_data() - 2);
     Position* p = new Position(b);
     moves.push_back(p);
  }
  TakeAwayBoard *b = new TakeAwayBoard(board->get_data() - 1);
  Position* p = new Position(b);
  moves.push_back(p);
  return moves;
```

}

I valgrinded my program and I'm apparently leaking memory. It seems that I'm deleting all unused objects, but perhaps I'm not understanding something. generate_moves() does allocate memory for each of the objects being pushed in. Evaluate returns 1. Does it seem possible that I'm leaking memory in any location?

Comment: Where does valgrind tell you the memory is lost?

Comment: You're leaking, because you're using `new` and `delete`. You never have to use `delete` in C++ and you need `new` only in very specific circumstances, which do not apply to your example. Pass data by value and use standard containers.

Comment: What about `TakeAwayBoard *b = new TakeAwayBoard(...)`? Do you free `*b` somewhere, for example in `Position::~Position()`? I guess we need a little bit more of your code (and an exact/complete valgrind error report).

Comment: You allocate lots of `TakeAwayBoard` objects and then push them into the vector. Where do you think you are deleting these objects? Because I can't see it in this code.

Comment: Where is the variable `best` declared?  Is it a member variable of `Solver`?  If so, then does it get delted in `Solver::~Solver()`?

Comment: Do a `valgrind --leak-check=full`. Also, is valgrind saying that your code is definitely leaking memory? Or is it just that you have still reachable bytes when the program finishes? Still reachable data is often acceptable.

Comment: @avakar What? If you need to use `new`, no matter how specific the circumstances, you'll need to use `delete` too!

Comment: ==14488== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 12
==14488==    at 0x4C28B35: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==14488==    by 0x401C57: TakeAwaySolver::generate_moves(Board*) (takeawaysolver.cpp:16)
==14488==    by 0x4015B0: Solver::negamax(Position*, int, int, int, int) (solver.cpp:29)
==14488==    by 0x40160D: Solver::negamax(Position*, int, int, int, int) (solver.cpp:33)
........
This is a part of my valgrind output, this is the reoccurring location, I clear best by using delete in another function.

Comment: @MrLister: If you use `new` then *something* has to use `delete` - but that should always be some kind of resource management object, not you. Unless you enjoy debugging memory leaks, of course.

Comment: I delete the board object in ~Position()

Comment: @MrLister, no, you don't use `delete`, you use `unique_ptr` (or `auto_ptr` if you don't have the former).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an if/else in which *move is only deleted in one of the paths.  I'd check there.

```
for(move = moves.begin(); move < moves.end(); move++){
          int val = negamax(*move,alpha, beta, -color, depth - 1 );
          if(val <= min){
            min = val;
            delete best;
            best = NULL;
            best = (*move)->get_board();
                                           //best is deleted, but *move is not
          }
          else{
            delete *move;
            *move = NULL;
          }
         }
```

Comment: That was it. I forgot to delete the *move pointer, so I just cloned moves board into best and delete move right after. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `std::vector<position *>` container will not automatically delete the inserted elements when it is destroyed. Make it a `std::vector<x<position *> >` where x is some suitable smart pointer template, like `auto_ptr`.

If you don't want to do that, then the next best thing is to wrap the vector in a class whose destructor iterates over the vector and calls delete on every pointer.

I.e. this is a memory leak:

```
{
   std::vector<int *> vec;
   vec.push_back(new int[3]);
   // vec goes out of scope
}
```

Sure, the vector cleans itself up! It deletes its internal array, etc. But it does nothing with the `new int[3]` that we allocated and put into the vector.

Comment: Would I be able to just use a vector pointer, and delete the vector, instead of wrapping the vector in a class? I feel like the vectors default destructor would already iterate over the elements and delete them.

Comment: The vector's default destructor will go over the elements and destroy them. Not delete them. That's a big difference!  An object like `Position *` is a basic C++ type. If we destroy that, nothing happens: it has an empty destructor, so to speak.  The only way a deletion happens for a vector element is if it is a class object which has a destructor, and that destructor deletes something. For instance if it is some `smart_pointer<Position *>` with a `smart_pointer<Position *>::~smart_pointer()` destructor which deletes the pointer that the smart pointer holds.

Comment: But the iterator is iterating over the elements that I am deleting, and if it's not stored in best, (which I delete later), it is deleted in the else right?

Comment: It cleans up the pointer objects... not the pointed-to memory.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but how is it cleaning up the pointer objects but not cleaning up the memory?

Comment: A pointer is a basic data type, like an int.  If you clean up an int, it frees the memory that the int was stored in.  Likewise, you can free the memory a pointer is stored in.  You have to do something extra to free the memory a pointer *points to* - that's what `delete` does.  Just letting the pointer go out of scope frees only the memory of the pointer itself, just like an `int`

Comment: But I delete the memory the iterator is pointing to in the else statement.

Comment: Pointer objects are not class objects; they are a concept inherited from the C language and provide no clean up.

Comment: You are trying to move the clean-up logic into the algorithm, but then it means that you have to get all your cases right not only from the point of view of the algorithm, but from the point of view of correct memory management. It would be easier to just leave the pointers alone during the algorithm, and clean them up in one fell swoop when the vector is no longer needed, liberating yourself to just getting the algorithm right. Think like a garbage collector. Dilbert's genius garbage collector, that is. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you never clear the 'minimum' positions.

You store a pointer to the board in `best`, and take care to clear that when you replace it with a better minimum, and in case the move isn't a minimum so far, you properly clean it up, but you never clean the actual position pointer in case it's a minimum.

As a side note, this is redundant:

```
    best = NULL;
    best = (*move)->get_board();
```